# Как зашифровать слово в цифры?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Подскажите пожалуйста как зашифровать слово в цифры. Подробнее:

- Есть сайт на котором люди регистрируется. Логин это есть email.
- После регистрации он может купить товар.
- После того как он покупает товар он переходит в личный кабинет и он получает код такого вида 5510-11321 где 5510 должен быть переконвертирован его email.

т.е. email duddeniska@list.ru = 5510. Как сделать конвертатор что бы у кажого e-mail был свои уникальные цифры.
Все это хочу написать на php. Спасибо!

Comment: Добавляйте в базу пару имейл-случайное число. При добавлении нового юзера на уровня кода генерируйте случное число и проверяйте есть ли оно в базе. Если нету, то присваиваем юзеру это число. Если число занято, то генерируем новое и все сначала.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что в код надо превращать именно e-mail? Я подозреваю, что у пользователей кроме e-mail есть ещё порядковый номер, просто Вы не хотите его светить, потому что тогда каждому будет понятно, сколько у Вас клиентов. Вам нужен алгоритм, который из одного уникального числа делает другое. Например, 1 -> 5510, 2 -> 7733, 3 -> 1025 и так далее, без всякой видимой системы. При этом число 1025 не должно получаться из какого-либо числа, кроме 3. Это называется биективное отображение. Простейший способ - XORить с константой и/или перемешивать биты определенным образом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уж велосипеды по получению некоторого уникального номера давно сделаны до вас.

Можно назначать юзеру [guid](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID), хранить его в базе и идентифицировать юзера по нему.
[Создание гуида в php](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.com-create-guid.php).
GUID - это и есть случайное число, 128 битное, что делает его уникальным в практических ситуациях.

Можно [захешировать](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D5%E5%F8%E8%F0%EE%E2%E0%ED%E8%E5) email, в php есть нативная поддержка [sha1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php), не забудьте [посолить](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)).
Хеш-функция- это как раз функция которая преобразует некоторый набор данных в некоторое число так, что по результату очень сложно определить, какой набор мы преобразовали.

Comment: @Volt, ТС просит (в примере 4 цифры) довольно короткое уникальное для хранимого у него множества e-mail число. 

Вряд ли числа из **30 и более цифр** на практике удовлетворяют его задаче.

Answer (score 0):

Хеш + рехеширование, например.